# Symfony, ошибка передачи параметра

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony3

Доброго времени. Возникает следующая ошибка:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Dontdrinkandroot\GitkiBundle\Twig\GitkiExtension::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security, instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker given, called in /var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 856 and defined
```

Собственно сам Extention:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class GitkiExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    /**
     * @var Security
     */
    private $securityContext;

    /**
     * @var ExtensionRegistryInterface
     */
    private $extensionRegistry;

    /**
     * @var RoleServiceInterface
     */
    private $roleService;

    public function __construct(Security $securityContext, RoleServiceInterface $roleService, ExtensionRegistryInterface $extensionRegistry){
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->roleService = $roleService;
        $this->extensionRegistry = $extensionRegistry;
    }
```

И сервис который передаёт параметры:

```
ddr.gitki.twig.gitki_extension:
    class: Dontdrinkandroot\GitkiBundle\Twig\GitkiExtension
    arguments:
        - '@security.authorization_checker'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __construct(
        AuthorizationCheckerInterface $securityContext,
        RoleServiceInterface $roleService,
        ExtensionRegistryInterface $extensionRegistry
        ){
    $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    $this->roleService = $roleService;
    $this->extensionRegistry = $extensionRegistry;
}
```